# How to validate value of each field inside element populated by ng-repeat in angular and display message correspondingly?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have several values that is fetched and needs to be displayed and made editable. I have applied validation on each of the field - it works fine, but I cannot display the message corresponding to that.

The relevant html is

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="HistoryController">
    {{invalidHistory}}
        <form name="histories" novalidate ng-cloak>
      <table border="1px solid black">
        <tr>
                    <td ng-repeat="h in history" ><input ng-model="h" name="history-{{$index}}" ng-class="{error: invalidHistory}" valid-history/>           <span>{{histories.history-$index.$error.invalidHistory}}</span></td>
              </tr>
      </table>
        </form>
    {{ histories | json}}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

The app.js is

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.service('HistoryService', function($http) {
    this.getHistory = function(){
        return $http.get('mock/history.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});

app.controller('HistoryController', function($scope, HistoryService) {
    HistoryService.getHistory().then(function(response){
        $scope.history = response.data;
    $scope.invalidHistory = "";
    });
});

app.directive('validHistory',function() {
    var regex = /(^\-3\.0$)|(^\-[0-2]\.[0-9]$)|(^[1-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]$)/;
    var link = function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {
      var validate = function(viewValue) {
        console.log(viewValue, typeof viewValue);
        var isValid = regex.test(viewValue);
        if(!$scope.histories.$dirty){
          ctrl.$setValidity('invalidHistory', true);
          return viewValue;
        } else if(isValid){
          ctrl.$setValidity('invalidHistory', true);
          return viewValue;                    
        } else{
          $scope.invalidHistory = "Invalid Value";
          ctrl.$setValidity('invalidHistory', false);
        }
      };

      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);
      ctrl.$formatters.push(validate);

      $attrs.$observe('invalidHistory', function(viewValue){
        // Whenever the comparison model changes we'll re-validate
        return validate(viewValue);
      });
    };

    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: link
    };
});
```

And the sample history is a json file: with following content:
`["1.6","1.8","-2.1","5.2","12.4","15.6","18.7","21.1"]`

How do I display the message when any of the values in the repeated input is not correct. Why `{{histories.history-$index.$error.invalidHistory}}` is always 0, even though the value is set to true or false in validation?

Thanks.

Comment: For now I have been able to get generic message when any of the fields has validation issues with the following.
`<span ng-show="histories.$error.invalidHistory.length > 0">Error in History</span>` in the form.